# How to use SearchCount method of Search Service Interface of atlassian 6.2.1?

Tags: jira, jinja2, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-mobile-connect

I am developing application related to jira. I want count of issues return by the jql query.
i got searchCount method in this [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/search/SearchService.html#searchCount%28com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20com.atlassian.query.Query%29) but i am not getting how to use this method using instance.

Answer (score 0):

The setup should look like this:

```
    String jqlQuery = "project=ABC"; // insert your JQL query here

    SearchService.ParseResult parseResult = searchService.parseQuery(currentUser, jqlQuery);

    if (!parseResult.isValid())
    {
        // errors in parseResult.getErrors().getErrorMessages()
        throw new MyException();
    }

    com.atlassian.query.Query query = parseResult.getQuery();

    com.atlassian.jira.util.MessageSet validateResults = searchService.validateQuery(currentUser, query);

    if (validateResults.hasAnyErrors())
    {
        // errors in validateResults.getErrorMessages()
        throw new MyException();
    }
```

With the resulting validated `query` object, you can then call `searchService.searchCount(currentUser, query)` to get your issue count.